# Fatal Error with NSLocalizedString due to one system language

Tags: swift, xcode, fatal-error, nslocalizedstring

I have recently started using localized Strings in my app and today I found this weird issue. For the time being, I support in my app two languages: English (the language of the project) and Italian (my native language). Today I tried changing my language to English and my app crashed with this error "Fatal Error Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"; now, I know this is an optional-related error but I do not understand what does it mean in this situation. Here's the code from the viewDidLoad method:

```
photosLabel.text = NSLocalizedString("photosLabelText", comment: "The text of the label under the photo's counter")
```

And here there's the line from the Localizable.strings (English)

```
"photosLabelText" = "Photos";
```

P.S. Looking around in my project I found that in the storyboard under the voice "Localization" English and Italian voice are different; here's the screenshot

[image]

Comment: Are you sure `photosLabel`  is not nil? in what context are you trying to set the `text` property?

Comment: Yes...I.m trying to set it in the viewDidLoad method...However the weird thing it's that if the language is Italian it works perfectly.

Comment: Don't you have localized storyboards (or xib)? You may have missed to connect IBOutlet in some of them.

Comment: Is setting `photosLabel.text` the only line where you are using `NSLocalizedString `? and are you sure it is the one giving this error?

Comment: @OOPer what do you mean?

Comment: You have multiple storyboards in your project, if you included storyboards when localizing.

Comment: @Carpsen90 I tried to print the "photosLabel" variable and the compiler gave me the same error. Btw I continue not understanding why this problem happens just with english

Comment: @OOPer I start thinking I didn't implement correctly the localizedString feature...Can you explain me how should I do this?

Comment: @LorenzoSantini I've updated my answer. It's an IBOutlet connection error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `photosLabel` is an IBOutlet, make sure that you link to it from the `(English)` storyboard not the `(Base)`.

Note: Change the name of your file `Localizable.string` to `Localizable.strings`, it's just a typo.

Comment: Sorry, my fault...I made a typo, yes, but inside this question, not in my project

Comment: Btw I have one more question. What are the differences between the Base main Storyboard and the English one?

Comment: Glad I could help

Comment: @LorenzoSantini The Base is the one used by the app by default, the other languages might be chosen by the user in the Settings. [This](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/InternationalizingYourUserInterface/InternationalizingYourUserInterface.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH3-SW2) is how base internalization is defined in the docs.